# Cookie returning null after setting?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to set a cookie forever, but its returning null when I try and get it? (The exit line).

```
class WelcomeController extends Controller
{
    public function begin()
    {
        Cookie::forever('next_welcome_step', 'language');
        exit('cookie: ' . Cookie::get('next_welcome_step'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By design, a cookie will only appear once the next page is loaded. Laravel uses the `setcookie` PHP function and contains this in [the documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php):

> Once the cookies have been set, they can be accessed on the next page load with the $_COOKIE array.

I'm not sure what version of Laravel you're using but in v5.0+ there's the [Cookie::queued](https://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Cookie/CookieJar.html#method_queued) method.